# SAX parsing progblem in android

Tags: android, xml, saxparser

Hi i have an android application and i want to get a data from xml file.
i have use SAX parser but there is some problem to get data from this type of xml file given here, so please given me the solution for
 parse the following xml file using SAX parsing

my xml file is here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xml>
    <movie>
        <file>
            <type>1</type>
            <url>http://www.mauitheatre.com/</url>
            <path>http://64.250.238.26:1111/clips/UlalenaSplashAdd.jpg</path>
            <title>UlalenaSplash</title>
        </file>
        <file>
            <type>0</type>
            <path>http://64.250.238.26:1111/clips/BaldwinBeach.mp4</path>
            <title>Baldwin Beach</title>
        </file>
    </movie>
    <movie>
        <file>
            <type>0</type>
            <url></url>
            <path>http://64.250.238.26:1111/clips/AppTeaser.mp4</path>
            <title>SlackKeyShow</title>
        </file>
        <file>
            <type>0</type>
            <path>http://64.250.238.26:1111/clips/BigBeach.mp4</path>
            <title>Big Beach</title>
        </file>
    </movie>
    <movie>
        <file>
            <type>1</type>
            <url>http://www.mountainapplecompany.com/new-releases/keola-beamer-and-raiatea</url>
            <path>http://64.250.238.26:1111/clips/raiateaADD.jpg</path>
            <title>Raiatea Keola Beamer add</title>
        </file>
        <file>
            <type>0</type>
            <path>http://64.250.238.26:1111/clips/CharleyYoungBeach.mp4</path>
            <title>Charley Young Beach</title>
        </file>
    </movie>
    <movie>
        <file>
            <type>1</type>
            <url>http://www.bennyuyetake.com</url>
            <path>http://64.250.238.26:1111/clips/BennyUyetake.jpg</path>
            <title>Benny Uyetake SPlash</title>
        </file>
        <file>
            <type>0</type>
            <path>http://64.250.238.26:1111/clips/HamoaBeach-1.mp4</path>
            <title>Hamoa Beach</title>
        </file>
    </movie>
    <movie>
        <file>
            <type>1</type>
            <url>http://www.dericksebastian.com</url>
            <path>http://64.250.238.26:1111/clips/DSSplash.jpg</path>
            <title>DS Splash</title>
        </file>
        <file>
            <type>0</type>
            <path>http://64.250.238.26:1111/clips/HanaBay.mp4</path>
            <title>Hana Bay</title>
        </file>
    </movie>
    <movie>
        <file>
            <type>1</type>
            <url>http://www.mountainapplecompany.com/new-releases/keola-beamer-and-raiatea</url>
            <path>http://64.250.238.26:1111/clips/raiateaADD.jpg</path>
            <title>Raiatea Keola Beamer add</title>
        </file>
        <file>
            <type>0</type>
            <path>http://64.250.238.26:1111/clips/KamaoleBeachPark1b-1.mp4</path>
            <title>Kamaole Beach Park 1</title>
        </file>
    </movie>
</xml>
```

Comment: Could you please paste the error? It's difficult to pinpoint the problem otherwise.

Comment: Also share your parser implementation, to let us see what can go wrong there. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you need an `ArrayList<Movie>`, where the structure of the `Movie` class is

```
public class Movie
{
    private ArrayList<File> files;
    public Movie()
    {
        this.files = new ArrayList<File>();
    }
}
```

and the `File`'s structure is

```
public class File
{
    private int type;
    private String url;
    private String path;
    private String title;
}
```

with the necessary `getter` and `setter` functions, you can get the desired list by

```
final SAXParser parser = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser();
final MovieXmlHandler handler = new MovieXmlHandler();
parser.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(yourXmlString)), handler);
final ArrayList<Movie> movies = handler.getRecords();
```

where

- `yourXmlString` is the xml data
  you've pasted above, and
- `handler` is a MovieXmlHandler
  instance.

MovieXmlHandler implementation:

```
public class MovieXmlHandler extends DefaultHandler
{
    private static final String TAG_MOVIE = "movie";
    private static final String TAG_FILE = "file";
    private static final String TAG_TYPE = "type";
    private static final String TAG_URL = "url";
    private static final String TAG_PATH = "path";
    private static final String TAG_TITLE = "title";

    private String currentNodeName;
    private Movie currentMovie;
    private File currentFile;

    private ArrayList<Movie> records = null;
    private String elementValue;

    public ArrayList<Movie> getRecords()
    {
        return records;
    }

    @Override
    public void startDocument() throws SAXException
    {
        super.startDocument();
        this.records = new ArrayList<Movie>();
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(final String Uri, final String localName, 
            final String qName, final Attributes att) throws SAXException
    {
        if (localName != null)
            currentNodeName = localName;
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(final char[] ch, final int start, 
            final int length) throws SAXException
    {
        if (this.currentNodeName == null)
            return;
        this.elementValue = new String(ch, start, length).trim();

        if (this.currentNodeName.equalsIgnoreCase(TAG_MOVIE))
            this.currentMovie = new Movie();
        if (this.currentNodeName.equalsIgnoreCase(TAG_FILE))
            this.currentFile = new File();
        else if (this.currentNodeName.equalsIgnoreCase(TAG_TYPE))
            this.currentFile.setType(Integer.parseInt(this.elementValue));
        else if (this.currentNodeName.equalsIgnoreCase(TAG_URL))
            this.currentFile.setUrl(this.elementValue);
        else if (this.currentNodeName.equalsIgnoreCase(TAG_PATH))
            this.currentFile.setPath(this.elementValue);
        else if (this.currentNodeName.equalsIgnoreCase(TAG_TITLE))
            this.currentFile.setTitle(this.elementValue);
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(final String Uri, final String localName, 
            final String qName) throws SAXException
    {
        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase(TAG_MOVIE))
        {
            if (this.currentMovie != null)
                this.records.add(this.currentMovie);
        }
        else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase(TAG_FILE))
        {
            if ((this.currentMovie != null) && (this.currentFile != null))
                this.currentMovie.getFiles().add(this.currentFile);
        }
        currentNodeName = null;
    }
}
```

Of course, if you have only the url of your xml data (`xmlUrl:String`), you can use

```
final URL sourceUrl = new URL(xmlURL);
final SAXParser sp = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser();
final XMLReader reader = sp.getXMLReader();
final MovieXmlHandler handler = new MovieXmlHandler();
reader.setContentHandler(handler);
reader.parse(new InputSource(sourceUrl.openStream()));
final ArrayList<Movie> movies = handler.getRecords();
```

and if you have your xml data available from an `in:InputStream`, then

```
final SAXParser parser = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser();
final MovieXmlHandler handler = new MovieXmlHandler();
parser.parse(in, handler);
final ArrayList<Movie> movies = handler.getRecords();
```

Let us know if this isn't what you were looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The real problem is that you are trying to use a SAX parser yourself; which makes life harder than it needs to be. If possible, why not rely on an Annotation based XML parsing framework like the [Simple XML](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) Library?

I just wrote a [blog post on how to include it in your Android projects](http://massaioli.homelinux.com/wordpress/2011/04/21/simple-xml-in-android-1-5-and-up/).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that the `<xml>` tag is not closed. To be able to parse the file, it must be a well-formed XML file, so try to add `</xml>` at the end and give it another try.

Comment: the xml tag was actually closed, but was not correctly formatted.

Comment: @rekaszeru: Ok, then we need more info ;)