# SAX parsing progblem in android when more then similar tag in xml file

Tags: android, parsing, saxparser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SAX parsing progblem in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730498/sax-parsing-progblem-in-android)

hi how to parse the xml using SAX parser when more then one similar tag is there

```
    <xml>
        −
        <movie>
        −
        <file>
        <type>1</type>
        <url>http://www.bennyuyetake.com</url>
        <path>http://64.250.238.26:1111/clips/BennyUyetake.jpg</path>
        <title>Benny Uyetake SPlash</title>
        </file>
        −
        <file>
        <type>0</type>
        <path>http://64.250.238.26:1111/clips/BaldwinBeach.mp4</path>
        <title>Baldwin Beach</title>
        </file>
        </movie>
        −
        <movie>
        −
        <file>
        <type>1</type>
        <url>http://www.kahumoku.com/Kahumoku/Store.html</url>
        <path>http://64.250.238.26:1111/clips/georgead1.jpg</path>
        <title>George Ad 1</title>
        </file>
        −
        <file>
        <type>0</type>
        <path>http://64.250.238.26:1111/clips/BigBeach.mp4</path>
        <title>Big Beach</title>
        </file>
        </movie>
        −
        <movie>
</xml>
```

here file tag is two times in movie tag and both values are different 
so how to parse such xml file

Answer (score 0):

[See answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5708915/android-passing-data-from-defaulthandler-class-to-activity/5709544#5709544) it explains what i think you need

in the XML handler you need to build a list of objects which will add a new object each time the start element is reached. When the XML parsing is complete you call the handler to receive back a list/array of all objects parsed from the xml

This is also a good tutorial which I leant from:

[Main Tutorial](http://www.anddev.org/novice-tutorials-f8/parsing-xml-from-the-net-using-the-saxparser-t353.html)

[Explaination howto parse multiple element XML like yours](http://www.anddev.org/novice-tutorials-f8/parsing-xml-from-the-net-using-the-saxparser-t353-15.html)

I hope that helps